# why I can select multiple radio buttons in this form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have **two** forms

only one of them is working probably "example 2"

and both of them are almost the same in terms of functionality

"example 1" is the one in question , "example 2" works fine.

```
 <h4>example 1<h4/>


<form class="answerFormClass" action="http://127.0.0.1:5000" method="PSOT" >

 <div name="choiceDivName_0" id="choiceDivId_0">
  <input type="radio" name="choice_radio_0" id="choiceId_radio_0" value="get">
  <label for="choiceId_radio_0">get</label>
</div>
<div name="choiceDivName_1" id="choiceDivId_1">
  <input type="radio" name="choice_radio_1" id="choiceId_radio_1" value="give">
  <label for="choiceId_radio_1">give</label>
</div>
<div name="choiceDivName_2" id="choiceDivId_2">
  <input type="radio" name="choice_radio_2" id="choiceId_radio_2" value="gone">
  <label for="choiceId_radio_2">gone</label>
</div>

  <input type="submit" name="submitBtnName" id="submitBtnid" value="CLick here"></button>
</form>

<h4>example 2<h4/>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"><br>
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"><br>
  <label for="other">Other</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="other" value="other"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

here is the code in codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zbOOMM?editors=1010

*"example 1" was created by a dynamic *java script* "example 2" found online*

Comment: Method = PSOT? Make it POST. And give your radio fields the same name.

Comment: Also note that you have a stray `</button>` tag after an `<input ...>` element, probably from converting a button from a `<button>...</button>` to an `<input type="button" ...>` at some point...

Answer (score 1):

Because radio buttons are grouped according to them having the **same `name`**, but your radio buttons all have different names. To make a group of radio buttons, give them all the same `name` attribute.

(Side note: You usually don't need an `id` attribute on radio button elements, but if you do have one, it doesn't have to be the same as its `name`.)

Here they are with the same `name`:

```html
<h4>example 1<h4/>

<form class="answerFormClass" action="http://127.0.0.1:5000" method="PSOT" >

 <div name="choiceDivName_0" id="choiceDivId_0">
  <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choiceId_radio_0" value="get">
  <label for="choiceId_radio_0">get</label>
</div>
<div name="choiceDivName_1" id="choiceDivId_1">
  <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choiceId_radio_1" value="give">
  <label for="choiceId_radio_1">give</label>
</div>
<div name="choiceDivName_2" id="choiceDivId_2">
  <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choiceId_radio_2" value="gone">
  <label for="choiceId_radio_2">gone</label>
</div>

  <input type="submit" name="submitBtnName" id="submitBtnid" value="CLick here">
</form>
```

Comment: damn you're fast TJ